# Launch a website as a mobile app using PhoneGap and have access to phonegap plugins

Tags: javascript, cordova, webview

I created an app with

```
window.location = 'http://www.google.de';
```

described by this tutorial: http://antonylees.blogspot.de/2013/02/launch-website-as-mobile-app-using.html

Is there a possibility to use

```
onclick="window.open('https://www.google.de', '_system');"
```

with cordova Plugin

```
 ́<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser" />
```

I read in the tutorial above it should be possible to access the phonegap plugins with

```
<access origin="http://your.website" subdomains="true"/>
```

But this doesn't work. Unfortunately it only opens inside of webview. But I want to open it outside of the webview in the browser.

Has anyone an idea?

Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, if you open it on a browser, then it isn't a phonegap app, it's a browser, and the browser doesn't have access to the phonegap API

And even in a phonegap app, you can't use the phonegap API if you are loading an external URL

Answer (score 0):

You can't because the point of PhoneGap and what makes it useful is the ability to be a native phone application. You can't run native phone applications on a web server. 
You can take the source and build off of that but, you can't just use the app on your website.